# Can I convert my html content into ipa file using XCode?

Tags: html, file

I have been searching a lot but still cannot find an answer.

I work as an Instructional designer, creating training content for my company. We have been using iPads for our training for quite a while now.

I have created a course with Adobe Captivate that I want to make it into a native app for internal use. I do not want to distribute it or publish on the AppStore it's just for the company.

Adobe Captivate allows you to publish into an App but via PhoneGap. To export it though to an app(.ipa file) you need the Apple Key which I don't have.

Adobe Captivate exports into html so I was wondering if I have more luck with XCode. I do not code or anything similar so I wanted to ask if downloading XCode will allow me to convert my htm file into an .ipa file or an app for internal use.

Many thanks,
Argi

Comment: If you want to build an app for iPad, you will need an Apple Key, no matter how you build your app. Anyway, in my opinion, your question on how to build your app is too broad for this site.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I do not want to know how to build the app. I want to know if it is possible to package my content into an .ipa file and use it on internal iPads.

Comment: Well, I think that whatever you do you will need an Apple Key. I would say that PhoneGap could be a good solution, but that's my opinion only.